# Update Different columns in different tables with same values

Tags: mysql

I am currently stuck.

I have 2 tables Named Employee and Employee_Review. In the Employee Table I have Column named Employee_ID and Job_ID and in the Employee_Review table the same columns name Employee_ID and Job_ID.

What I want to do is update the Employee_Review Job_ID column with the Employee table Job_ID Value where the Employee_ID is equal to the Employee_Review Column Employee_ID.

IS this in anyway possible?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Try (as in backup first) something like

```
UPDATE Employee_Review er
JOIN Employee e on e.employee_id = er.employee_id
SET er.job_id = e.job_id
WHERE e.employee_id = er.employee_id
```

Basically says update the `Employee_Review` table .. joining the `Employee` table and setting `Employee_Review` `Job_Id` to equal `Employee` `Job_Id` .. where `Employee` `Employee_Id` = `Employee_Review` `Employee_ID`

Make sense ???